# Populating HTML Table from spreadsheet data

Tags: html, google-apps-script, web-applications, google-visualization

I'm working on simple "query based" Web app which would retrive certain data from sheet which is used by multiple people. People who use this app should never see full  spreadsheet file.

GAS CODE:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate();
}

function getData(e) {
  var id = "1ui99w7eNFwRz_ck66eXH503IyhxYQVNR96HW4HusJCI";
  var data =         SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName("Requests").getDataRange().getValues();
  var ar = [];
  data.forEach(function(f) {
    if (~f.indexOf(e.searchtext)) {
      ar.push(f);}});
  return ar
Logger.log(ar)
}
```

HTML FILE:

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form>
    <input type="text" name="searchtext">
    <input type="button" value="ok" onClick="getData(this.parentNode)" />
    </form>
    <pre id="disp"></pre>

    <html>
      <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['table']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

      function drawTable() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Key');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Booking Key');
        data.addColumn('boolean', 'WHS Accepted');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Booking Date');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Booking Time');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Loading');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Supplier');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Suppliers');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Dock');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Driver name');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Plate No.1');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Plate No. 2');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Truck Type');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Pallet places');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Note');
        data.addColumn('boolean', 'Canceled ');

        var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

        table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%'});
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="table_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

So far I got this:

Header of Web: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IA5mh.jpg

I input certain code in App, code retrieve my data in array, but I am struggling with populating the table with my data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `google.script.run` to load data from server
- Directly add the received array to visualization

#### Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script>
      const loaded = new Promise((res, rej) => {
        google.charts.load('current');
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(res);
      });
      let wrapper = null;

      async function drawTable(arr) {
        await loaded; //wait if charts is not loaded
        wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          chartType: 'Table',
          dataTable: arr,
          containerId: 'table_div',
        });
        wrapper.draw();
      }

      function getData(form) {
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(drawTable)
          .getDataFromServer(form);//change server function name
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="text" name="searchtext" />
      <input type="button" value="ok" onclick="getData(this.parentNode)" />
    </form>
    <div id="table_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### code.gs Snippet:

```
function getDataFromServer(e) {
  var id ="ID";
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)
    .getSheetByName("Requests")
    .getDataRange()
    .getValues();
  var ar = data.splice(0,1); //add headers
  data.forEach(function(f) {
    if (~f.indexOf(e.searchtext)) ar.push(f);
   });
 return ar;
}
```

#### To Read:

- [ChartWrapper](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/drawing_charts#chartwrapper)
- [`google.script.run`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: Thank you solved my problem :) also thank you for some extra documentation definetly will go trough it :)